# Inline styles causing problems when replacing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with a script I'm working on which grabs the same HTML element from an API and updates it every 20 seconds. I have scripts in place that watch for changes in a data-attribute which then animates it into view if it detects a change.

The problem I'm having is keeping the bar consistent after it appears the first time. If I add the `display: none` inline property to the element, or if I use jQuery to hide the element on page load the script is over-writing the element which causes it to disappear again.

This is the HTML element:

```
<aside id="alert" class="row" style="display: none" data-supressed="false" data-path="path_here">
</aisde>
```

This is what the Javascript looks like:

```
  function reloadBar() {
  /* Fires every 20 seconds. */

    var $alert = $("#alert");
    var path = $alert.data('path');

    /* Performs an AJAX call on the feature path. */
    $.ajax ({
      url: path + secondary-path,
      success: function(data) {

        /* If successful it will replace the bar with the new bar. */

        /* Grabs the updated element from the API */
        var newBar = $($.parseHTML(data.rendering)).find('#alert');
        var newBarHtml = newBar[0].outerHTML;

        var currBarSupp = $alert.data('supressed');
        var newBarSupp = newBar.data('supressed');

        /* If the new bar is supressed and old one is not, hide it. */
        if (!currBarSupp && newBarSupp) {
          $alert.animate({height:0});
          $alert.parent().animate({height:0}, function() {
            $(this).hide()
          });
        }

        else {

          /* Replaces the element */
          $alert.replaceWith(newBarHtml);

          /* If the new bar is not supressed, update it and animate it into view. */
          if (!newBarSupp) {
          updateBar(true);
          }
      }
    }
  })
};
```

updateBar() will fire which animates it into view:

```
function updateBar(isReload) {
    var $alert = $("#alert");

    if (isReload === true) {
      $alert.css("display","block")
      $alert.animate({height:"45px"});
      $alert.parent().animate({height:"45px"}, function() {
        $(this).hide().show("slow");
      });
    }
  }
```

After 20 seconds the reloadBar script will fire again and will return the `display: none` property back to the aside element, which causes it to disappear when it shouldn't.

Is there a more consistent way I can keep that property off/on the element? Anything that adds any kind of inline style/classes to the element causes problems with it. I've found even if I try using a .hide() when the script initially fires it will still replace the element and remove `display: none`, so the problem will happen both ways.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would be better if you share a fiddle to help you. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu I don't really have a way to create a Fiddle for this otherwise I would have

Comment: I think replacing the html is the bad culprit here. Couldn't you rather read the `var content = newBar[0].innerHTML` and set the html on your $alert element like `$alert.html(content)` ?

Comment: @Icepickle I agree, but the jQuery needs to read from the data-attributes somehow. They would need to be updated somehow.

Comment: @JamesIves Only to update the properties? And do you know which properties you 'll receive? Do they have to be all there? Or only some of the properties you use, like display & path?

Comment: @Icepickle The data path and data-supressed etc get updated when a toggle is switched on the backend which pushes it through the API, the script then re-renders the HTML block and decides if it should hide/show the element. That's the idea at least. It just keeps overriding properties, such as if display: none was placed by jQuery it just wipes it out the next time it runs the script as it's not part of the object in the API. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: @Icepickle Managed to solve this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by using a string slice on the HTML element and patching the CSS elements to it. First I saved the current elements style properties using `var currStyles = $alert.attr("style");`

Afterwards I split the string of the updated element which is fed through the API and added the inline styles to it. I assigned this to a new variable called updatedBar:

```
var updatedBar = newBarHtml.slice(0,6) + ' style="' + currStyles + '"' + newBarHtml.slice(6);
```

And then I replaced that element on the page with the updatedBar variable.

```
$alert.replaceWith(updatedBar);
```

The script now keeps the inline styles consistent after it grabs the new element from the page so the jQuery hide() and show() work as intended now.